# Applications don't recognise internal storage partition 2 mounted as external sd card

Tags: mount, partitions

So I have a Chuwi Hi10 Plus running RemixOS 2.0 (Android 5.1.1). This was originally a dual boot tablet, but I deleted Windows, so now the device has 45 gigs of storage free on the drive. I formatted this part as Fat32, because I wanted to mount it as an sd card. I modified the fstab file in the boot image, to mount this new partition where normally an external sd card would get mounted. The partition gets correctly mounted, I can read and write it with Root Explorer, but the applications don't see it, so I can't really use it. What else do I have to do so that all the applications on the device recognise it?

The original fstab file (I included only the relevant part):

```
##############################################################
# Source: device/intel/mixins/groups/storage/sdcard-mmcblk1-4xUSB-sda-emulated/fstab
##############################################################
*/block/sda*                            auto             vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk:auto
*/block/sdb*                            auto             vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk2:auto
*/block/sdc*                            auto             vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk3:auto
*/block/sdd*                            auto             vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk4:auto
*/block/mmcblk1*                        auto             vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto
/dev/block/mmcblk1p1                    /sdcard          vfat    defaults                                   recoveryonly
```

The modified version (last 2 lines):

```
##############################################################
# Source: device/intel/mixins/groups/storage/sdcard-mmcblk1-4xUSB-sda-emulated/fstab
##############################################################
*/block/sda*                            auto                 vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk:auto
*/block/sdb*                            auto                 vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk2:auto
*/block/sdc*                            auto                 vfat    defaults                                   voldmanaged=usbdisk3:auto
dev/block/mmcblk1p1                     /mnt/media_rw/usbdisk4    vfat    defaults                                   defaults
dev/block/mmcblk0p12                    /mnt/media_rw/sdcard1     vfat    defaults                                   defaults
```

As you can see, I also modified the second to last line, because I wanted to have the actual external sd card mounted at usbdisk4, since the new partition would be mounted in its place. I set the flag to defaults, because the voldmanaged option wasn't working. Below you can see a screenshot of the partition succesfuly mounted:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: App see only `voldmanaged` partitions.

Comment: But it didn't mount in that mode, so I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: it's stupid behaviour of stock android (and windows) to mount first partition only, maybe try another rom (if there is any alternative to RemixOS)? for example LineageOS does mount all partitions (not sure about the voldmanaged stuff)

Comment: Try `/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 auto vfat defaults voldmanaged=sdcard2:auto` or `/dev/block/mmcblk0p12 auto vfat defaults voldmanaged=sdcard1:auto` or `*/block/mmcblk0* auto vfat defaults voldmanaged=sdcard1:12` etc. But storage configuration before Android 6 was a bit complex. So you may additionally need to define an `sdcard` `init` service and modify `framework-res.apk`. See references here: https://source.android.com/devices/storage/config-example. An easy but limited way is to not rely on `vold` and mount the filesystem with correct permissions from `fstab` or `init.d` script or `init` service